# ffmpeg. How do I encode a gif and make two outputs, one with padding one without without generating the pallet twice?

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

I'm trying to create 2 gifs from the same source.  One gif has a border around it, the other one does not.  I can run separate commands but encoding the gif and generating the palette information twice takes to long.  I'm processing hundreds of gifs so speed is necessary.  I would like to be able to encode once, generate the palette once, and then split the output so that one output has the border and the other one does not.  Is this even possible?

I'm encoding gifs using the following ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=-1:72,crop=72:72,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen=max_colors=32[p];[s1][p]paletteuse=dither=bayer:bayer_scale=3" -r 15 -loop 0 output.gif -y
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this with a complex filtergraph:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "scale=-1:72,crop=72:72,split[s0][s1];\ [s0]palettegen=max_colors=32[p];\
[s1][p]paletteuse=dither=bayer:bayer_scale=3,split[gif0][g1];\
[g1]<add your padding filter chain>[gif1]" \
-map [gif0] -r 15 -loop 0 output0.gif \
-map [gif1] -r 15 -loop 0 output1.gif
```

Comment: thanks.  Unfortunately I couldn't get this to work.  Either the border wouldn't show up or the palette wouldn't be applied. But this did point me in the right direction.

Comment: I coudln't get the palette and padding to even work on their own.  I ended up making a png border image and applying that as an overlay.  The following worked: ```ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i overlay.png -filter_complex "[0]scale=-1:72,crop=72:72,split[s0][s1]; [s0]palettegen=max_colors=32,split[p1][p2];[s1][p1]paletteuse=dither=bayer:bayer_scale=3,split[gif0][g1];[g1][1]overlay=format=auto[f1];[f1][p2]paletteuse=dither=bayer:bayer_scale=3[gif1]" -map [gif0] -r 15 -loop 0 output0.gif -y -map [gif1] -r 15 -loop 0 output1.gif -y ```